# Joint PMF sum question with zero probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a question about the summation of a joint PMF. So I have this table of joint PMF here:
[image]

The question is, what is the value of C? Now here's what I know: there are 29Cs altogether, but what I am not sure is that whether I should divide 12 or 9(excluding the cells with 0 probability) by 29?

I have doubts because for questions such as $Y| X=1$ for example, the cells with 0 value is ignored, so only 3C is counted.

Comment: First of all I count $29C$´s. This term must be 1.

Comment: When you´re awake, give a reply.

Comment: @callculus, oops sorry, I miscounted them. Guess I had a very long day. Edited the question. Anyway, yeah I figured it out using your hint. So thank you!! I guess the cells with 0 values are not counted also then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Any discrete pdf should add to 1. Here, what is the sum of all values in the table? What is $C$ so that the sum is $1$?

P.S.: Please double-check your answer. $30C$ is not correct.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your answer.I guess I overthink it. The cells with 0 probability are not counted, right?

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 0):

The equation is $29C=1$. Thus $C=\frac1{29}$. That means , for instance, that $P(X=-2,Y=1)=\frac{5}{29}$. And therefore

$$f_{Y|X=1}(x,y)=\begin{cases}  \frac{\frac7{29}}{\frac7{29}+\frac3{29}+\frac3{29}}, \ y=1 \\ \ldots,  \ y=0 \\ \ldots,  \ y=-1 \\ 0,  \ \textrm{elsewhere}  \\ \end{cases}$$

Simplify and replace the $...$